# Laravel Appzcoder generator error

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I am currently using this laravel CRUD generator

https://packagist.org/packages/appzcoder/crud-generator on my remote VPS on digital ocean.

Setup is okay but I cant run generator on remote VPS.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Call to undefined method Appzcoder\CrudGenerator\Commands\CrudControllerCommand::qualifyClass()

This error occurs.

Comment: did you try updating symphony?

Comment: Removed irrelevant tag and removed 'Help!'